# Rails check if variable differs from record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to see if my variable differs from the corresponding record in the database.I am aware of ['attribute'_changed? method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html), but it only works if you updated the record through the variable.

Example

```
user = User.first # name = bar
u.update(name: "foo")
u.name_changed? # => true
```

however, in this case (integration testing for example)

```
u = User.first # name = bar
User.first.update(name: "foo")
u.name # => 'bar'
u.name_changed? #false
u.reload
u.name_changed #false
```

I want to check if my variable *u* differs from User.first in some attribute, which wasn't change through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in. All you can do is load another user from database and compare their attributes.

```
u = User.first # name = bar
User.first.update(name: "foo")
u.name # => 'bar'
u2 = User.find(u.id)
u.name == u2.name # => false
```